# ggplot2 variables within function

Tags: r

Feel I am making a very dumb mistake here.. as I've done this before on another project (maybe luck?)

Goal is to construct several graphs in ggplot via use of a function. I eventually want all the graphs displayed on a single page, etc...

Here is an example of a single ggplot that works:

```
if (require("ggplot2") == FALSE) install.packages("ggplot2")

data_df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=20))
time=1:nrow(data_df)

ggplot(data=data_df, aes(x=time, y=data_df[,1])) + 
        geom_point(alpha=1/4) + 
        ggtitle(deparse(substitute(data_df[1])))
```

Note there are other functions that will be called within this that will change based on the dataframe column called.
I followed another working example I had made, but this just gives me an error. I feel like I'm making an elementary mistake but can't put my finger on it!

```
if (require("ggplot2") == FALSE) install.packages("ggplot2")

data_df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=20))
time=1:nrow(data_df)

graphit <- function(sample_num){
        ggplot(data=data_df, aes(x=time, y=data_df[,sample_num])) + 
                geom_point(alpha=1/4) + 
                ggtitle(deparse(substitute(data_df[sample_num])))
}

graphit(1)

#Error in `[.data.frame`(data_df, , sample_num) : 
#  object 'sample_num' not found
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're doing several things wrong.

First, everything specified inside `aes()` should be *columns in your data frame*. Do not reference separate vectors, or redundantly call columns via `data_df[,1]`. The whole point of specifying `data = data_df` is that then everything inside `aes()` is evaluated *within* that data frame.

Second, to write functions to create `ggplot`s on different columns based on arguments, you should be using `aes_string` so that you can pass the aesthetic mappings as characters explicitly and avoid problems with non-standard evaluation.

Similarly, I would not rely on `deparse(substitute())` for the plot title. Use some other variable built into the data frame, or some other data structure.

For instance, I would do something more like this:

```
data_df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=20))
time=1:nrow(data_df)
data_df$time <- time

graphit <- function(data,column){
    ggplot(data=data, aes_string(x="time", y=column)) + 
        geom_point(alpha=1/4) + 
        ggtitle(column)
}

graphit(data_df,"X1")
```

Comment: thanks so much. i did finally get the code working thanks to your explanation. i'm sure i'll reference this answer in the future

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment due to rep count. Joran's solution (and advice on ggplot2) is highly recommended.

Here is a highly not recommended hack that will get your code to work. Add this line as the first line of your function.

```
assign(x = "sample_num", value = sample_num, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Alternative synthax for the same code above is `sample_num <<- sample_num`.

The issue you are facing is an scoping issue. `sample_num` exists only within the `graphit()` environment and is not defined within the `ggplot()` environment.

Comment: thanks this was a good shortcut to simply get the code working, i realize now i need to learn more about scoping